# Display stack trace elements exclusive only the Java classes that I wrote

Tags: java

[image]

As you see, these are all stack trace elements. **I only want the yellow part** that have blue fonts (clickable to identify the java class and its line number where the exception was thrown) **to be printed** as the rest of the stack traces are excess and redundant.

I managed to display those stack traces using:

```
public static void displayStackStraceArray(StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements) { 
    for (StackTraceElement elem : stackTraceElements) {
        System.err.println("\t"+elem.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Giving us colors won't translate to any actual code, because the code only "knows" about the text on each stack trace entry.  Can you tell us what _text_ we should search for to find the elements you want?

Comment: Here's the javadoc of StackTraceElement: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StackTraceElement. Stop using the android package for your own classes, respect the Java naming conventions, and then check if the stack trace element is for one of your classes or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JB Nizet notes in a comment, you should use your own specific package instead of starting it with android.

```
public static final String PACKAGE_ROOT = "org.example.application";

public static void displayStackStraceArray(StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements) { 
    for (StackTraceElement elem : stackTraceElements) {
        if (elem.getClassName().startsWith(PACKAGE_ROOT)) {
            System.err.println("\t"+elem.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. This is one good way. I'll try using package root. (i didn't downvote)

Comment: I got this working now as it get rids of excess trace elements. Thank  you.

Answer (score 3):

You may check each stack trace entry for mention of your class file at the end of the line:

```
public static void displayStackStraceArray(StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements) { 
    for (StackTraceElement elem : stackTraceElements) {
        String line = elem.toString();
        // assuming the file is called Search_Task.java:
        if (line.matches(".*\\(Search_Task\\.java:\\d+\\)$")) {
            System.err.println("\t"+elem.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This of course works for the given example case, but I would consider an approach that works for any project far more useful. (My downvote)

Comment: @Vulcan I have never had the need to search a stack trace this way in the first place.  I always can by eye, and I usually get good mileage this way.  But, this does answer the exact question.

Comment: However this line: (line.matches(".*\\(Search_Task\\.java:\\d+\\)$") 
is a hard coded way to check. I have plenty of classes not just Search_Task.java. IntelliJ is smart to make other stack elements colored-blue so that we are directed to the java class and its line number where the exception is thrown by left-click.

Comment: I imagine one use to be filtering logged exceptions to only display what point in one's code is relevant, in which case you would want a solution that works for all classes in your project. The title of the question asks for elements from "only the Java classes that I wrote" and not only *this* class. Hence my downvote ("this answer is not useful").

Comment: @DaryllDavidDagondon Then you make the file name a variable, and add it to the pattern.  I only showed that you can scan each line and use regex to fish out what you want.  That being said, this should not be a substitute for learning how to read a stack trace.  I seldom have a need to do anything like this, because I can usually see at a glance where my code is.

Comment: @DaryllDavidDagondon all your own classes should be in a specific package (**not** starting with android, but looking like `com.yourcompany.yourproject`). Filter based on that. And, again, respect the other Java naming conventions: SearchTask and not Search_Task. Conventions exist for a reason.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not sure what is actually in between `Search` and `Task`.  It looked like an underscore at first, but now I'm thinking it is just blotted out data.  Oh well.

Comment: @JB Nizet I am not using Search_Task.java in the project. I am just hiding the true class name using underscore.

Comment: JB Nizet's package naming suggestion and Tim's answer bought Vulcan a clue. Thank you all for your help.